# What is the most efficient way of extracting some numbers from a data point in R? (Plus other specific steps!)

Tags: r, string, performance, dataframe, vector

I've got quite a specific problem, for which I can just about find a very hacky solution, but I'm hoping somebody could outline a slightly more elegant method.

I have a CSV file, consisting of one row per historical football match played. The fields I care about look something like this:

```r
home_team <- c("Team A", "Team B", "Team B")
away_team <- c("Team C", "Team C", "Team D")
home_goals <- c(2, 0, 1)
away_goals <- c(1, 2, 0)
home_goal_mins <- c("5 60", "NA", "80")
away_goal_mins <- c("15", "20 40", "NA")

df <- data.frame(home_team, away_team, home_goals, away_goals, home_goal_mins, away_goal_mins,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df
#>   home_team away_team home_goals away_goals home_goal_mins away_goal_mins
#> 1    Team A    Team C          2          1           5 60             15
#> 2    Team B    Team C          0          2             NA          20 40
#> 3    Team B    Team D          1          0             80             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My goal is to transform this dataframe such that there is one line per goal scored, per game, like this:
[image]

The main challenges, as I see them:

1. The `*_goal_mins` fields are read in as strings containing both numbers and NAs
2. Replicating the rows such that the Home/Away team combinations have the same number of rows as the total number of goals for that match

With regards to (1), I've been using `stringr::str_split(., " ")` to extract the numbers but then struggle to transform them into a numeric vector. Taking the first row of `df` as an example, I'm struggling to transform `"5 60"` into `c(5, 60)`, and it gets harder for me when I try to combine the home team's `"5 60"` with the away team's `"15"` to get the full goal sequence of `c(5, 15, 60)`.

As for (2), my current approach is to calculate the `total_goals_scored` per match, and do the following:

```
expanded_df <- df[rep(seq_len(dim(df)[1]),
                      df$total_goals_scored), ]
```

but I sense that there may be a better method.

Any help or tips will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` library you could do

1. bring `home_goal_mins` and `away_goal_mins` in same column using `pivot_longer`.
2. Split the data on whitespace and separate the goals in separate rows
3. Drop `NA` values
4. `arrange` data based on timestamp
5. Get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(home_goal_mins, away_goal_mins)) %>%
  separate_rows(value, sep = ' ', convert = TRUE) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  arrange(home_team, away_team, value) %>%
  group_by(home_team, away_team) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider()

#  home_team away_team home_goals away_goals   row home_goal_mins away_goal_mins
#  <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl> <int>          <int>          <int>
#1 Team A    Team C             2          1     1              5             NA
#2 Team A    Team C             2          1     2             NA             15
#3 Team A    Team C             2          1     3             60             NA
#4 Team B    Team C             0          2     1             NA             20
#5 Team B    Team C             0          2     2             NA             40
#6 Team B    Team D             1          0     1             80             NA
```